# Signal recovery using Majorization-Minimization with Quadratic Upper Bound

Tags: matrices, optimization, algorithms

I am trying to formulate a majorization-minimization (MM) (via quadratic upper bound) approach to total variation denoising (TVD). The total variation denoisng objective function is defined as an unconstrained optimization problem with

$$ 
\underset{\mathbf{x}}{\text{min}}\quad \frac{1}{2}||\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}||_2^2 + \lambda ||\mathbf{Dx}||_1
$$

The data fidelity term $\frac{1}{2}||\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}||_2^2$ is most suited for gaussian noise. $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{y}$ are vectors of size $n \times 1$. $\mathbf{x}$ is the clean signal to be estimated and $\mathbf{y}$ is the observed noisy signal.  $\mathbf{D}$ in the total variation (TV) regularization term is an $n \times n$ first order difference matrix
$$
  \mathbf{D}=\begin{bmatrix}      
  &-1   & 1    &\ldots & \ldots &\ldots \\
  &\vdots   & -1    &1 &\ldots &\ldots \\
  &\vdots  &\ldots &\ddots &\ddots &\ldots\\
  &\vdots  &\ldots &\ldots  &-1  &1\\
  \end{bmatrix} 
$$

To use the MM steps to the TVD objective function, we apply a quadratic majorizer function to the TV regulizer. An example majorizer function for $f(t) = |t|$ is
$$
 g(t) =\frac{1}{2|t_k|}t^2 + \frac{1}{2}|t_k|
$$

So, we can majorize the TV regulizer with $g(t)$.

let $t = v(n)$, and following the MM approach
$$
 \sum_n \left[\frac{1}{2|v_k(n)|}v^2(n)  +  \frac{1}{2}|v(n)|\right] \geq \sum_n|v(n)|
$$
This can be written compactly in matrix form as
$$
\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{v}^T \Lambda_k^{-1} \mathbf{v}  +  \frac{1}{2}|\mathbf{v}| \geq ||\mathbf{v}||_1
$$

where $\Lambda_k$ is defined as a matrix
$$
 \Lambda=\begin{bmatrix}      
  &|v_k(1)|   &     &\ &  &  \\
  &    &     &|v_k(2)| &  & \\
  &   &      &        &\ddots &\\
  &  &       &       &  &|v_k(N)|\\
  \end{bmatrix} \\
  =\text{diag} (|v_k|) 
$$

Using $\mathbf{Dx}=\mathbf{v}$ we can re-write the above equation as
$$
\frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{D}^T \Lambda_k^{-1} \mathbf{Dx}  +  \frac{1}{2}||\mathbf {Dx_k}||_1 \geq ||\mathbf{Dx}||_1 
$$

where $\Lambda_k := \text{diag}(\mathbf{Dx})$. After some manipulations, we get the final majorizer function as
$$
G_k(\mathbf{x}) = \frac{1}{2}||\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}||_2^2  +  \lambda  \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{D}^T \Lambda_k^{-1} \mathbf{Dx}  +  \lambda \frac{1}{2}||\mathbf{Dx}_k||_1 \quad , \quad \Lambda_k = \text{diag}(|\mathbf{Dx}_k|) 
$$

To find the solution $\mathbf{x}_k$ we minimize the obtained majorizer function  $G_k(\mathbf{x})$
$$
\mathbf{x}_{k+1} = \underset{\mathbf{x}}{\text{min}} \quad \frac{1}{2}||\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}||_2^2  +  \lambda  \frac{1}{2}\mathbf{x}^T \mathbf{D}^T \Lambda_k^{-1} \mathbf{Dx}  +  \lambda \frac{1}{2}||\mathbf{Dx}_k||_1
$$

Obtaining the closed form solution
$$
\mathbf{x}_{k+1} = \left( \mathbf{I} + \lambda \mathbf{D}^T \Lambda_k^{-1}\mathbf{D}\right)^{-1} \mathbf{y}
$$

This is the update equation for $\mathbf{x}$ at each iteration $k$. Because there is a possibility where division by zero will occure in the matrix $\Lambda_k^{-1}$ as the value of $\mathbf{x}$ are minimized at each iteration, we re-write the update equation using the matrix inverse lemma, obtaining a more stable update equation that is
$$
\mathbf{x} =  \mathbf{y} - \mathbf{D}^{T} \left( \frac{1}{\lambda} \mathbf{\Lambda}_k + \mathbf{D}\mathbf{D}^{T}  \right)^{-1} \mathbf{D}\mathbf{y} \quad; \quad \text{$\mathbf{\Lambda}_k=$ diag$(|\mathbf{Dx}|)$}
$$

recall, that this is the formulation for TVD with Gaussian noise in which the data fidelity term

is $\frac{1}{2}||\mathbf{y}-\mathbf{x}||_2^2$.

For Poisson noise, it has been shown in various papers that the data fidelity term should be replaced by
$$
 \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\log(\mathbf{x})
$$

Thus the new optimization problem,
$$\underset{\mathbf{x}}{\text{min}} \quad \mathbf{x}-\mathbf{y}\log(\mathbf{x}) + \lambda ||\mathbf{Dx}||_1
$$

My question is, can this objective function be minimized using the MM method with the quadratic

upper bound ? If so, is the formulation steps the same as the one above. Please let me know if

more information or clarification is needed.